# Compress XML during XMLReader.Read()

Tags: c#, xml, compression, xmlreader

I have a method which loops through an XML document using an `XMLReader` (validating at the same time) extracting specific pieces of information.  I also need to **compress** the entire XML document in preparation for storing it in a database.  The code I have to do this is below.  **Is this** (passing the entire `XmlReader` to `StreamWriter.Write()`) **the appropriate / most efficient way to achieve this?**  I didn't see a clear way to use the `while(validatingReader.Read())` loop to achieve the same result.

```
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemaSet.Add("schemaNamespace", "schemaLocation");

XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
readerSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
readerSettings.Schemas.Add(schemaSet);
readerSettings.ValidationEventHandler 
                 += new ValidationEventHandler(XMLValidationError);

using (XmlReader documentReader = requestXML.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree())
{
    using (XmlReader validatingReader = 
            XmlReader.Create(documentReader, readerSettings))
    {
        using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (DeflateStream gzip = 
                    new DeflateStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = 
                        new StreamWriter(gzip, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    writer.Write(validatingReader);
                    this.compressedXMLRequest 
                                    = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
        while (validatingReader.Read())
        {
            // extract specific element contents

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference:

The code in the Question does not work properly.  Passing an `XmlReader` to a `StreamWriter` doesn't work as expected.  In the end I didn't end up combining compression with validation in this way so I don't exactly have "correct" code to show for this but didn't want to leave the question dangling.

Answer (score 0):

Compression portion looks fine. MemoryStream may not be the best choice for large documents, but check if performance is ok for your scenarios before changing.

"extract specific element" portion will not read anything as reader is forward only, so all content is already read by the time that portion is executed. You may want to recreate the reader.

Comment: The compressed result is under 5Mb.  I assume this is acceptable for a MemoryStream?  Is there no way to write the reader content to another stream while also being able to extract specific XML element content?

Comment: MemoryStream can handle arbitrary size, the question is if it is fast enough for your case. The problem is when MemoryStream grows it has to copy previous content to newly allocated array - may not be fast enough, the time spent doing so may be measurable on large (~1MB+) streams.

Comment: I don't know of easy way to write content of a reader to stream and extract elements at the same time.

Comment: if you are worrying that data is too big, use BufferedStream on top of a file stream instead of MemoryStream